# Cómo hacer un Deploy Application a Azure

Tags: genexus

En la Wiki habla de  target "Microsoft Azure Functions" pero no encuentro esa opcion dentro de la lista desplegable.

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?49351,Deploy+to+Azure+Functions
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dónde configuro en el Deploy Unit los datos de:

1. application id
2. tenant id
3. secret id ?

Comment: y ya preguntaste en el proveedor??? a lo  mejor no tienen la documentacion actualizada  o te hace falta algún paso...

Comment: Hola Amigo, te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask], 
[mre], 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este documento https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?47430,Azure%20Functions se aclara a partir de qué versión de GeneXus se soporta esto y para qué generador además de los tipos de funciones que se pueden hacer deploy desde GeneXus.

Comment: Entonces no nos aplica para la instalación que tenemos en el trabajo.
Aqui utilizamos GX17 upgrade3, y desarrollamos con ".Net Enviroment (C#).
FrameworkPath="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319".

Comment: Exacto, esta nueva funcionalidad sólo se soporta para el nuevo generador .NET (.NET Core, que para el Upgrade 5 requiere .NET 5 y a partir del U7 se requerirá .NET 6). No está previsto soportar esto para el generador .NET Framework (C#)